# Use of unicode N prefix with quote escape

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem where I need to store the select statement as a value in a field in database for the web service to execute it later and show the result in a different application.

When I update the value with the select statement in the table escaping the single quotes I loose the unicode `N` prefix functionality.

Example:

```
update table
set sqlstatement = 'select No as N''Ī'' from table'
where ID = 1
```

When executing the saved SQL statement, the column name is returned as 'I' not 'Ī' 
Is there any special way to escape single quotes when using `N` prefix?

Comment: I would have thought you would need N on the main string as well as the nested string in order for the unicode character to be preserved properly. So something like `set sqlstatement = N'select No as N''Ī'' from table'`

Comment: You need to ensure that `sqlstatement` column is `nvarchar` and prefix the value you are assigning with `N`. eg: `set sqlstatement = N'select No as N''Ī'' from table'
w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add N to the head of 'select No as N''Ī'' from table'

```
declare @table as table(id int identity(1,1),sqlstatement nvarchar(100))
insert into @table values('select No as N''Ī'' from table') 
--before
select sqlstatement from @table where Id=1

declare @sqlstatement as nvarchar(100)
update @table
set sqlstatement = N'select No as N''Ī'' from table'
where ID = 1

--After
select sqlstatement from @table where Id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am dumb.. the main string containing SQL statement should be inserted in N'' as well for it to be considered as unicode. Figured it out the next morning after posted the question.. Still thanks for the answer!